# Как можно совершить редактирование в SQlite c C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

В данный момент реализовано добавление в БД, теперь записанные данные не получается редактировать, имеется форма XAML, заполняется, сохраняется, так же и показываются данные находящийся там, вопрос как можно совершить редактирование строк данных и вывод?
В данный момент выдает ошибку "Имя не существует в данном контексте"
Прикладываю код с попыткой редактирования строки в БД

```
 public partial class Edit : Window
{
    AppContecst db;
    public Edit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //db = new AppContecst(); //обращение к класу подключения базы данных выделение памяти
        AppContecst db = new AppContecst();
        List<AppStaff> AppStaffs = db.AppStaffs.ToList();
        staffList.ItemsSource = AppStaffs;
    }
    private void Button_Ed_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (staffList.SelectedItem == null) return;
        // получаем выделенный объект
        AppStaff appStaff = staffList.SelectedItem as AppStaff;

        Edit edit = new Edit(new AppStaff
        {
            Name = Edit.name,
            Famil = Edit.famil,
            Otches = Edit.otches,
            
        });

        if (edit.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            // получаем измененный объект
            appStaff = db.AppStaffs.Find(Edit.AppStaff.id);
            if (appStaff != null)
            {
                appStaff.Name = Edit.AppStaff.name;
                appStaff.Famil = Edit.AppStaff.famil;
                appStaff.Otches = Edit.AppStaff.otches;
                db.Entry(appStaff).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Так же класс модель БД

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace WpfApp1
    {
    class AppStaff

    {
    public int id { get; set; }
    private string  name, famil, otches, pol, podrazdel, dolzhnost, kabinet, telefon_rab, 
    telefon_lichni, pochta, data_rozhde, mesto_rozh, grazhdan, semeinoe;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public string Famil
    {
        get { return famil; }
        set { famil = value; }
    }
    public string Otches
    {
        get { return otches; }
        set { otches = value; }
    }
   public string Pol
    {
        get { return pol; }
        set { pol = value; }
    }
    public string Podrazdel
    {
        get { return podrazdel; }
        set { podrazdel = value; }
    }
    public string Dolzhnost
    {
        get { return dolzhnost; }
        set { dolzhnost = value; }
    }
    public string Kabinet
    {
        get { return kabinet; }
        set { kabinet = value; }
    }
    public string Telefon_rab
    {
        get { return telefon_rab; }
        set { telefon_rab = value; }
    }
    public string Telefon_lichni
    {
        get { return telefon_lichni; }
        set { telefon_lichni = value; }
    }
    public string Pochta
    {
        get { return pochta; }
        set { pochta = value; }
    }
    public string Data_rozhde
    {
        get { return data_rozhde; }
        set { data_rozhde = value; }
    }
    public string Mesto_rozh
    {
        get { return mesto_rozh; }
        set { mesto_rozh = value; }
    }
    public string Grazhdan
    {
        get { return grazhdan; }
        set { grazhdan = value; }
    }
    public string Semeinoe
    {
        get { return semeinoe; }
        set { semeinoe = value; }
    }

    /* public string Img
    {
    get { return img; }
    set { img = value; }
    }*/
    public AppStaff() { }
    public AppStaff(string name, string famil, string otches , string pol, string podrazdel, 
       string dolzhnost, string kabinet, string telefon_rab,
        string telefon_lichni, string pochta, string data_rozhde, string mesto_rozh, string 
        grazhdan, string semeinoe)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.famil = famil;
        this.otches = otches;
        this.pol = pol;
        this.podrazdel = podrazdel;
        this.dolzhnost = dolzhnost;
        this.kabinet = kabinet;
        this.telefon_rab = telefon_rab;
        this.telefon_lichni = telefon_lichni;
        this.pochta = pochta;
        this.data_rozhde = data_rozhde;
        this.mesto_rozh = mesto_rozh;
        this.grazhdan = grazhdan;
        this.semeinoe = semeinoe;
     

    }
}
}
```

код для получения доступа к БД

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WpfApp1
{
class AppContecst : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AppStaff> AppStaffs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    
    public AppContecst() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

}
}
```

Прикладываю XAML разметку

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Edit"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"

    Title="Edit" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Background="#D7D7D8">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Border Margin="10,51,19.6,70" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="40" MaxWidth="5050" CornerRadius="15" >
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="30" Color="LightGray"></DropShadowEffect>
            </Border.Effect>
            <StackPanel Height="157">
                <TextBlock Text="Добовление нового сотрудника" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0.2,20"/>
                <Grid  Margin="0,0,0,20">
                    <Button x:Name="Button_Save"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Сохранить" Click="Button_add_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Button_Uvol" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,0,0,5" Content="Уволить" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Click="Button_Close_Click" />
                </Grid>
                <ListBox x:Name="staffList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>

                                <TextBox  x:Name="textboxName" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Имя" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="0,0,950,0" Text="{Binding Name}">

                                </TextBox>
                                <TextBox x:Name="textboxfamil" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Фамилия" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="300,-40,650,0" Height="36" Text="{Binding Famil}"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="textboxotches" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Отчество" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="600,-40,300,0" Height="36" Text="{Binding Otches}"/>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="textboxpol" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Пол" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}" Margin="0,20,950,0" Text="{Binding Pol}">
                                    <TextBlock>Мужской</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Женский</TextBlock>
                                </ComboBox>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="textboxpodrazdel" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Отдел" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}" Margin="0,0,950,0">
                                    <TextBlock>Административный отдел</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Финансовый отдел</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Совет муниципального района</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Информационно-аналитический отдел</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Экономический отдел</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Юридический отдел</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Бухгалтерия</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Муниципальный контроль</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Отдел опеки и попечительсва</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Сельскохозяйственый отдел</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Комитет по управлению собственностью</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Технический отдел</TextBlock>
                                </ComboBox>
                                <TextBox x:Name="textboxdolzhnost" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Должность" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="0,0,950,0"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="textboxkabinet" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Номер кабинета" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="0,0,950,0"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="textboxtelefon_rab" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Телефон рабочий" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="0,0,950,0"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="textboxtelefon_lichni" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Телефон сотовый" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="600,-325,300,0" Height="36"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="textboxpochta" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="E-mail" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="0,0,950,0"/>
                                <DatePicker x:Name="textboxdate_rozhde" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Дата рождения" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintDatePicker}" Margin="300,-400,650,0" Height="36" />
                                <TextBox x:Name="textboxmesto_rozh" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Адрес проживания" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="0,0,950,0"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="textboxgrazhdan" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Гражданство" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Margin="0,0,950,0"/>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="textboxsemeinoe" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Семейное положение" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}" Margin="0,0,950,0" >
                                    <TextBlock>Женат/Замужем</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock>Холост/Незамужем</TextBlock>
                                </ComboBox>
                                <Image x:Name="Imageboxfoto" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Foto" Margin="950,-640,50,10" Height="215" OpacityMask="#FF948B8B" ></Image>
                                <Button x:Name="Button_Foto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="120,-380,100,10" Content="Обзор" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Click="Button_Foto_Click" />


                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>
          </Grid>
  </Window>
```

пока пытаюсь выдать три элемента, это name, famil, otches

Comment: `В данный момент выдает ошибку "Имя не существует в данном контексте"` на какую строку ругается?

Comment: ``authUser.Name = AppStaffs.Name;`` --> ``authUser.Name = Staffs.Name;``

Comment: @Blackmeser, ошибка исчезла, но XAML форма пустая, он не чего не выводит((

Comment: Беда, но к сожалению отсюда плохо видно вашу xaml разметку.

Comment: И зря вы убрали изначально проблемный код.

Comment: @Blackmeser

Вернул все, проблема та же, уже третий день сижу ((

Comment: @ 
aepot Добавил)